# iOS IPA file could not be installed because it's integrity could not be verified

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, ipa

After installing ipa file on my iPad 14.2 version this error prompt.

> " this app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be
> verified"

[image]

what should i do?

iOS version: 14.2

Certificate: Enterprise provisioning certificate.

N.B: In other version like 10.3.3 it's working fine.

Comment: Hi you found any solution for this?

Comment: I have had same issue and here is work around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735693/1151916

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue after trying many times. Actually my app was built in Enterprise certificate. But I am trying to generate IPA using Development option that's why it is not recognised by new devices. So how i fix the issue??

> Ans: I generate IPA file using Enterprise build option and using
> enterprise distribution certificate and it's working perfectly for new
> devices also and the error pop-up gone.