# Integrity could not be verified

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, xcode, react-native

I have created have in react-native. I can run app in Xcode simulator successfully. But when I created ipa file and run in IOS device, it gives me error 'app cannot be installed because its integrity can not be verified'.
Can anybody tell what is the issue  ?

Comment: I have had same issue and here is work around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735693/1151916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple solutions:

1. Restart your iOS device if you have recently updated iOS version and also restart the Xcode.
2. Run your app in device and check the VPN & Device Management in Settings App -> General -> VPN & Device Management. It will asks for the certificate access.
3. Check the Developer Mode is enabled on the device or not.
4. Check Keychain if profiles & certificates are trusted.

Answer (score 6):

Please add Device `UDID` to the App Store developer account. And also update provision profile that includes device `UDID` and after that create new ipa using updated provision profiles.

Comment: By this, Can I able to run app on any ios device?

Comment: No, Only on those devices that you have added UDID in App store

Comment: How can I run ipa in all iphone devices @Nisha ?

Comment: Thanku @Nisha
Added udid in Apple store works

Comment: Already I am having device UDID added still I am getting the same issue? What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: same here i am also getting this issue

Comment: I am also getting same issue. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

I also suffered from this but found the correct solution. So the issue is When making a build either build it for production and upload it to the app store or build it using an `ad-hoc` profile.

An `ad-hoc` profile is an Internal testing profile that allows the app to be installed and used in certain specified iPhones using UIDs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in expired provisioning profile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).