# "Unable to install app" iOS app instllation issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

this app cannot be installed because its integrity couldn't be verified.

getting this error on some devices with iOS 14.5 while on some it work fine with same iOS version. Also working fine on simulators of same iOS version.

Anyone getting similar issue or have some hint to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Dump current certificates.  And create them over again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appcenter iOS install error "this app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029781/appcenter-ios-install-error-this-app-cannot-be-installed-because-its-integrity)

Comment: @ElTomato i tried this, created new CSR, generated new Distribution certificate, deleted old ones, removed account from xcode preference, restarted mac, add account in xcode preferences , installed newly generated Distribution certificate but still same error

Comment: A distribution certificate?

Comment: @Spydy Ever find a solution?  I have suddenly had this start happening and cannot come up with anything.  Have reset everything from scratch but still cannot install apps

Comment: @JoeH actually this error due to multiple reasons, 1) make sure device UDID is added in provisioning profile, 2) check if there is some external Embded Library with signing different cert. for my case it was ZoomSDK screen sharing sdk, when i removed problem solved,

Comment: @Spydy in our case its an issue with the azure pipeline tasks not signing/provisioning correctly.  Changed to using the Archive process to then do an ad-hoc release (using the same cert and profile) and everything worked fine