# This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified. FireBase ios

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I am facing a problem installing a testing app through Firebase app distribution. But just one of the apps. The profile is installed, UDID is added. Just one particular app does not launch. Any suggestions?

Comment: found solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App Center iOS install error: "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029781/app-center-ios-install-error-this-app-cannot-be-installed-because-its-integrit)