# Failed to install .ipa file on IOS device

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, ipa

I'm trying to install .ipa release of my flutter project on a physical IOS device but as I'm not fully familiar with IOS there were some problems moving the file from mac to iphone and install it. finally I used [installonair.com](https://installonair.com) ,but when I try to open it the following error comes up:

"**This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified.**"

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH8y3.jpg)

I tried going to Settings -> General -> Profiles and it says "No profiles are currently installed."

I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue or other ways of installing .ipa file on IOS devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appcenter iOS install error "this app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029781/appcenter-ios-install-error-this-app-cannot-be-installed-because-its-integrity)

Comment: @AbdulHoqueNuri Not really, isn't there any way without an apple developer account?

Comment: No, It is impossible to install an IPA without developer account. You need to create certificate and add devices to that account for IPA installation to iOS device.

Comment: It's impossible. You need a developer account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use over-the-air installs for your own devices in the first place? If you're using an iOS device you physically have with you, installing to it is as simple as plugging it into your Mac and running the app from Xcode. Alternatively, try the `flutter run` command.

If you want to install to a device you can't do these steps for and must use over-the-air (for example, when installing to a cloud device, or to your friends/colleagues/clients), make sure its UDID is added at https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/ (I'm pretty sure you'll need a Paid Apple Developer account for that.), then re-build/re-sign.

Comment: Actually I want to upload the file so everyone can download and use it by trust the app in the Settings. Is it even possible without an apple developer account? (I can't upload it to AppStore for some reasons)

Comment: To install an ad-hoc build on a device, the device needs to be registered in your account and included in the provisioning profile. You need a paid Apple developer account to register more than one device.  People can't just "trust" arbitrary apps

Comment: Installing an unsigned ipa is possible on a jailbroken device, but I won't specify any details on that. Indeed, ad-hoc apps built the official Apple way require a paid Apple Developer account and are limited in terms of how many devices you can install them on (a limit which doesn't apply to apps published and approved on the App Store).