# Developer integrity could not be verified, iOS Enterprise

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, enterprise

On my latest Enterprise/In House build attempt, I'm getting the developer integrity could not be verified error on install. In the past, this was because my device's UDID was not a part of the provisioning profile. However, now it seems like I can't add UDID's to Enterprise provisioning profiles at all. Any profile marked Universal Distribution can't add device ids.

I can add device ids to Ad Hoc profiles but I can't install apps signed with this type of profile to a physical device. I need the Enterprise/In House profile, but I need to be able to add device ids. I thought I could do this in the past but perhaps I'm mistaken. I know that until very recently, I did not have problems installing apps signed with In House profiles. Now I can't.

I'm trying to distribute through Microsoft Appcenter btw. Any thoughts?

Comment: Enterprise signed apps are not limited to specific UDIDs; That is the point of the enterprise program.  If the app is not distributed via an MDM profile then the user does need to go into Settings->General->Profiles and trust the enterprise developer before the app can run.  You need to make sure that your enterprise signing certificate hasn't expired.  Since you didn't have a problem until recently this may well be the case

Comment: I did check the cert expiration. It's still valid. Perhaps I am confusing an In House profile with an Ad Hoc profile. However I tried both and they both gave the same error.

Comment: Start with archiving an app and signing it with your enterprise certificate directly in Xcode. If that works then you need to look at your appcenter setup

Comment: I have had same issue and here is work around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735693/1151916

Answer (score 2):

For anyone (including future-me) who still have this issue despite attempting everything else in these or other links *and* also have an embedded "App Extension": there is a *separate* `embedded.mobileprovision` file within the `Your.appex` bundle (within the app, in the `Plugins` directory). You'll have to "Show Package Contents" on both the app and the .appex. This wonderful file is automatically created *only if it does not already exist*, and you have no warning if it about to expire tomorrow. To cause it to be recreated on your next Distribution build, you must find the matching entry within `/Users/<You>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` and delete it. You can then check your new build to ensure it's been regenerated with another full year of expiry.