# Xamarin Deploying iOS App Ad Hoc Failing to Install

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to deploy an iOS app Ad Hoc to an iPhone for beta testing. I've been developing the app on Windows VS, I have a Macbook air with all the necessary software (Xcode, VS, etc), and I have paired to it with VS on my Windows machine. I have also followed the following steps:

1. Created an Apple Developer account
2. Created an App ID with the bundle identifier as the same exact one as the one in info.plist
3. Created a signing certificate using my Macbook Air, downloaded it, and installed it into XCode
4. Created a provisioning profile with the App ID and the certificate, and made sure to include the device that I want to load the app onto.
5. Made sure everything above was set to "distribution" and "ad hoc" as needed.
6. Set Bundle Signing in my iOS project properties to Manual Provisioning, and selected the Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile to the ones that I created for this deployment.
7. Set the build to Release and the target to Remote Device
8. Ensured that the deployment target in info.plist was set to the highest available, which is 15.4, though my iPhone is at 15.6 (could this be the problem?)
9. Set the IPA Packaging Options to "Build iTunes Package Archive (IPA)"
10. Set "Include iTunesArtwork images and the iTunesMetadata.plist" to true in the same area
11. Successfully built the iOS project and produced a .ipa file

After all that, I've been trying to get the .ipa onto my phone, which is definitely the device I added to the provisioning profile.

I've tried two methods to do this, and both have failed:

1. Connecting my phone to my Windows machine and opening iTunes. Dragging the .ipa file onto the device. The app shows up on my phone, but when I try to open it, I get this error:
   **"This app could not be installed because its integrity could not be verified"**. Though it should have been.. The device is linked to the provisioning profile that was used to create the darn thing.
2. Connected my phone to my Macbook Air and accessed the device through XCode > Window > Devices and Simulators. I emailed myself the .ipa file and downloaded it onto the machine (the Microsoft docs explicitly state that emailing the .ipa should work just fine). In the "Intalled apps" section of the device, I clicked the little '+' and then pointed it to the downloaded .ipa. After a few seconds, it pops up an alert window that says **"Unable to install *.iOS"**.

Other things I have tried since this has been a problem:

1. Recreating the above steps by re-registering my device, creating new certificates, downloading, installing, all that business.
2. Messing with the deployment target version.
3. Jumping out from behind the couch and startling it to make it do what it's supposed to.

I swear I'm done with Xamarin forever after this problem is solved, but all the headaches I've experienced have made me think twice about whether to even bother with .NET Maui haha thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I've had similar issue but only after creating new adhoc provisioning profile after the old one expired. All works fine if I distribute the app via the Mac, but not from VS2022.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the error **This app could not be installed because its integrity could not be verified"** may be caused by the proper certificate or the test devices are not visible in 'Devices' (UDIDs added) in `developer.apple.com/account`.I found two simialr issues, you can refer to them: [link1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669544), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029781/appcenter-ios-install-error-this-app-cannot-be-installed-because-its-integrity).

Secondly, have you follow [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=macos#creating-an-ipa) on how to generate the `IPA` file?