# Flutter: can't install .ipa file into iphone 6S plus

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I've generated **.ipa** file from XCode and tried to install it into my iphone 6s using Apple Configurator. App got installed but it's showing `This app can't be installed because its integrity could not be verified`.

I've tried possible solutions that I've found by searching into google like set on airplane mode, WIFI during installation. I've tried to set Trus Developer from Device management. But I haven't found something like that into device management into my iPhone.

Need solution to get out of this? Need Help..

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066663/12838877

Comment: make sure you have added you phone as testing device on apple console

Comment: Thanks to all for giving response. I've solved the issue. I've generated .ipa file in development mode and then turn on flight mode and turn off wifi while installing the .ipa. After completing the installation process need to restart iphone. This works for me.

Comment: @pmatatias, First time I've export .ipa using App Store connect option. This occurs the issue. But I can't run the .ipa while generating using the Ad-Hoc option. It's showing white screen while opening my app. What is the best option to generate the ipa?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

- You have to add UDID of that particular phone.
- Check your internet connection.